# sc is not defined in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

SparkContext function is returning error in pyspark in cmd and Jupyter

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sc' is not defined
```

I have tried:

```
>>> from pyspark import SparkContext
>>> sc = SparkContext()
```

But still showing the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\spark\python\pyspark\context.py", line 115, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "c:\spark\python\pyspark\context.py", line 275, in _ensure_initialized
    callsite.function, callsite.file, callsite.linenum))
**ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app
=PySparkShell, master=local[*]) created by getOrCreate at c:\spark\bin\..\python
\pyspark\shell.py:43**strong text****
```

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you had another notebook executing pySpark, you could use  **SparkContext.getOrCreate()**.

Regards.